# How to modify the Eclipse Run Configuration classpath?

Tags: java, eclipse, junit, osgi, eclipse-jdt

I'm developing a project in Eclipse JDT, that has optional dependencies on OSGI - that is, it supports being used as an OSGI bundle, and if it is used as a bundle inside an OSGI environment, it will also reference some classes from OSGI.

Now I want to write JUnit test cases for both running inside OSGI and running without OSGI, included in two different test suites. The OSGI tests are run as JUnit Pulg-in Tests and the Non-OSGI tests should be run as normal JUnit Tests.

Now I have the problem, that I couldn't find any way in Eclipse to exactly specify the classpath for the JUnit Test Run Configuration and exclude the optional OSGI jars.

Is there any way to exclude jars or modify the default classpath for an Eclipse Run Configuration?
If not, does anyone have a suggestion, how one should setup JUnit tests in such a case?

The only solution I was able to find is, to create a jar file from my unit tests and run the tests without OSGI from a different project with the test jar file on the classpath. But I would prefer a more elegant solution, ideally without the necessity of a second test project.

Comment: If I look in the Eclipse run configurations (run -> run configurations...), I see a 'classpath' tab that allows you to hand-tailor it for that run configuration.

Comment: @Gimby Are you able to remove entries from this classpath tab? I'm only able to add new entries there (using Eclipse Luna M5). I'm also not able to see the exact classpath - just the names of referenced projects and virtual classpath folders like 'Plug-in Dependencies'.

Comment: perhaps my situation is easier because I use Maven. But yes, I can do all that although I'd have to overrule what Maven does for me. Note: I use TestNG, not JUnit. Perhaps that matters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the help of Gimbys comment, I was able to solve the problem. Although it is not possible in Eclipse to modify the default classpath generated by JDT, it is possible to entirely remove the default classpath and then add your own classpath in the classpath tab of the Runtime Configuration.

To remove the default classpath, one has to select the root entry that is named after the currently run project, and then click on the "remove" button. After that one can add all the jar files and projects that should be loaded in the classpath. The downside of this approach is, that jar files, that are normally provided by Eclipse plugins like e.g. junit.jar, must then also be selected manually (e.g. by adding it to a library folder of the project or by selecting the external jar in the plugins directory of the Eclipse installation folder).

Comment: I have Maven Project, and even if I remove the Maven Entry from the Dependencies Tab under the Classpath node, when I click the show command line, I still see Maven Dependencies showing in the classpath. How I can override to remove/add a specific jar from the classpath in debug/run config dialog box?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you split up your project in 4 separate projects:

- **Logic**: This package contains all the logic, so basically what your program/plug-in does
- **Logic.plugin**: This Project resembles a Plugin-Project (OSGI-Bundle). This project contains only configurations needed for your plugin and everything dependent on osgi. It has a dependency on your Logic Project.
- **Logic.plugin.test**: All the test cases for your osgi bundle. It is the normal plugin approach to split up logic and test cases
- **Logic.cli**: This project contains the command line interface (or whatever your alternate application is). This also depends on the Logic project.

If your CLI project is only very small you may merge it with the Logic project.

Comment: Yes, this would certainly be the way to go, if I had complete control over the project. But the OSGI bundle is already used in a production environment, and the support for using it without OSGI was added later. There is currently no way to entirely separate the OSGI logic from the non-OSGI logic without also breaking the API...

Comment: It is not very nice but can you move the JUnit testcases to a single project? Do you use any build software (mvn, gradle, ant)?

Comment: The JUnit testcases are already in a different project, but this project also has dependencies on OSGI. I guess I could move the Non-OSGI tests into a separate project and reference it from the OSGI test project... but I would still prefer a way to somehow modify the classpath for the Runtime Configuration if possible.